# ProtoBuffer files generated after building project missing dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to create implement client-server communication with the help of grpc

proto file -

```
syntax="proto3";

package com.project.grpc.roleservice;

message UserRequest {
    string userName=1;
}

message RoleReply {
    string userRole=1;
}

service UserRoleFromServer{
    rpc getRoleUser(stream UserRequest) returns (stream RoleReply);
}
```

Gradle build -

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5")
    }
}


plugins {
id 'java'
}


apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

group 'com.project.grpc.roleservice'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1"
}
plugins {
    grpc {
        artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.16.1'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
        grpc {}
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile( 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.16.1')
compile('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.16.1')
compile('io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.16.1')
compile 'io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:3.0.0'
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile (group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12')
}
```

After building the project all the files are generated in a build folder and a UserRoleFromServerGrpc is generated which I want to extend and implement in my server-service file

But The UserRoleFromServerGrpc has a lot of errors it asks for following dependencies

Streamobserver needs io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.16.1 ,grpc-core

Add io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.16.1 to classpath

but I have already defined these dependencies in gradle build

How to resolve this issue

Screenshot of IDE

[image]

Comment: I used your build.gradle with Gradle 4.9, commented out the spring and mysql pieces, and had no trouble building. I see the .classes for UserRoleFromServerGrpc in build/

Comment: In my case also classes are being generated but when i use them in my project the UserRoleFromServerGrpc has error like can't MethodDescriptor can not be resolved add grpc-core 1.16.1 to class path . Is it something i am doing wrong 
how to use the files when generated do i have to import them or directly use these files in my project

Comment: Please refer my screenshot and comment what i am doing wrong

Comment: It works for me with IntelliJ 2018.1 and Gradle 4.9. I remember there were issues IDE issues like that with much older versions (of Gradle, I think).

Comment: If you can't figure it out, adding the generated code to the source sets manually is a workaround: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.16.1/examples/build.gradle#L59-L67

Comment: Yeah that works but still it is not a good practice when developing enterprise level api's

Comment: To clarify, are you encountering errors when building the project (e.g., on the command line with `./gradlew build`) or only having trouble getting your IDE to recognize the dependencies? It sounds like it's just an IDE problem, not a build issue. If so, what IDE/version are you using?

Comment: build works fine , I did some research and I found out  it was IDE issue .Thanks man